# F5 loading balancing - Routing requests to specific server in pool when specified in the request?

Tags: load-balancer, f5

I have several web applications that are load balanced by an F5 appliance. What I would like to know is, **for support reasons**, is there a way to form an HTTP Request and have the F5 appliance route it to that specific server rather than the normal random load balancing?  Is there maybe an HTTP Header or something or does a specific rule need to be made to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, protocols above OSI layer-4 (e.g. HTTP) are explicitly off-topic here. The F5 configuration would be on-topic.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with iRules.

The admin override would request the page adding a cookie like so:

```
http://somesite.com?override=web1
```

Then the iRule would look for an an HTTP Cookie of `override` using the [HTTP::cookie](https://devcentral.f5.com/Wiki/iRules.HTTP__cookie.ashx) command. Then an `if` or `switch` statement matching `web1` which would assign the session to a particular web server using the **[node](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iRules.node.ashx)** command.